# How to get redundant consistent (duplicate) data from the database using relational algebra?

Tags: mysql, database-design, duplicates, relational-algebra

I have 2 relations (tables):

Shops (Postcode (PK), SuburbName, BottleShopName (PK), Address),
People (PersonName (PK), Postcode (PK), AlcoholConsumption)

If I write down a query that will return the name of the each bottle shop in the
database and its suburb using relational algebra, it would look like this:

**π BottleShopName, SuburbName (Shops).**

The limitation of this query is that it would **not** show any redundant data. Say if there are two different Bottle shop names with the same name and are in the same suburb having the same post code, the above query would ignore the second one.

What modifications should I make to this query to get both results explicitly using relational algebra?

Comment: And what did you learn when you googled 'site:stackoverflow.com  (duplicate OR duplicates) relational algebra'?

Comment: Should the answer give you SQL?  Or Relational Algebra?

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is missing the used query, here's what I understood of your question:

```
SELECT BottleShopName, SuburbName FROM Shops JOIN People ON People.Postcode = Shops.Postcode WHERE People.PersonName = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

> Say if there are two different Bottle shop names with the same name and are in the same suburb having the same post code, the above query would ignore the second one.

Relational algebra relations are sets of tuples. They cannot have two tuples with all the same values for attributes.

A relation holds the rows that make a true statement from a given *predicate*--a fill-in-the-blanks sentence template parameterized by attribute names.

Suppose that Shops holds rows where "a bottle shop has postal code *Postcode*, suburb name *SuburbName*, name *BottleShopName* and address *Address*". If, for some particular values of *Postcode*,  *SuburbName*, *BottleShopName* & *Address*, there is more than one shop with postal code *Postcode*, suburb name *SuburbName*, name *BottleShopName* and address *Address*  then there is still only one tuple with those values in the relation.

If there could be more than one shop and you want to know that then you need a different predicate. You could keep a count of similar shops: "*N* bottle shops have postal code *Postcode*, suburb name *SuburbName*, name *BottleShopName* and address *Address*". Or you could assign a unique *name* or *id* to each shop and then use: "a bottle shop identified by *id* has postal code *Postcode*, suburb name *SuburbName*, name *BottleShopName* and address *Address*". (Still no duplicates possible.)

The reason relations are sets of similar tuples in the relational model is that if relations R and S have predicates r and s then:
R JOIN S has predicate (holds the tuples where) r AND s,
R UNION S has predicate (holds the tuples where) r OR s,
R MINUS S has predicate (holds the tuples where) r AND NOT s,
RESTRICT *condition* R has predicate (holds the tuples where) r AND *condition*,
RENAME A N R has the predicate (holds the tuples where) r with *A* replaced by *N*, and
PROJECT A R has predicate (holds the tuples where) FOR SOME *attributes other than A*, r.
Ie a query also has a predicate and its tuples are also the ones that make its predicate into a true statement. So querying means writing a predicate for which we want the satisfying tuples.

In SQL, tables can have duplicate rows. So you cannot reason this way about what rows should be in a table in a given application situation, what a table states about the application situation in terms of the rows in it, or what rows a query is asking for in terms of its inputs, its operator and the application situation--except in special cases. (Eg it doesn't make sense to talk about a row stating something by being in a table.) This is perhaps the most profound way that SQL violates the relational model and is pointlessly harder to use.